# Stack Overflow For Teams should have the option to notify the entire team via email about a posted question

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-for-teams

My group is trying out Stack Overflow for Teams, and I see a neat feature where you can notify certain users about a question. That being said, I work with a fairly small team that has quite a bit of cross-training, so any one of them may be a good person to answer any given question.

Unfortunately, most of my team are not Stack Overflow addicts like me, so unlikely they would be watching the feed for new questions. At least not off the start.

*The goal is simple:* Enable users to notify the entire or a predetermined subset of their team without having to type each name, as I am sure that will get old very fast. Imagine you had to enter each name every time you need to send an email to your entire team.

*I suggest a two-tier approach:*

1. Enable something like `TeamName` or `@All` that can be typed into the **Notify** textbox. This will send a notification to everyone on the team upon submission. Of course this list should not need any maintenance from users as new members join and old members are removed. This will likely be most userful for smaller teams like mine.
2. Enable creation of "Notify Lists" much like one would create email lists in Outlook, for example. This will be useful for small and medium sized teams, and I would think VERY useful for larger teams. Some suggested rules of engagement:

   - Admin and Team Leaders can create new lists.
   - Only Admin can delete existing lists.
   - Admin and Team Leaders can add or remove any user from any list.
   - Regular Users can join or remove themselves from any existing List.

Perhaps this is already possible, but I have scoured the help and there doesn't seem to be a mention of this anywhere. Please let me know if anyone is aware of a possible solution.

**Edit - Added Aug 17, 2018**
Just to make the information readily available for anyone reading this page, Chance Heath from Stack Overflow was kind enough to inform that:

> Good news, we're conducting discovery as we speak on this very feature. I don't have a solidified delivery date or anything, but we are working on it.

Comment: I imagine an @all ping request, that accidentally also works on the main site and someone types it and Stack Overflow crashes due to the emails being sent out to every single user. That'd be fun to see.

Comment: Hey @Nik - thanks for this feedback! Good news, we're conducting discovery as we speak on this very feature. I don't have a solidified delivery date or anything, but we *are* working on it. Thanks again for giving a +1 for wanting this.

Comment: There should also be a setting for adding @all by default, which would be useful for small teams that want all new questions to be pushed to the entire team by default. Or alternatively a profile setting for subscribing to all new questions.

Comment: Is there an update to this? I am trying to convince my medium sized company to use stack overflow for QA, but without this feature of having everyone notified with a new question, they will not go for this idea. Would love to have a chance to show how great stackoverflow is

Comment: Isn't the whole idea to _prevent_ the whole "email the entire team every time we have a question and see who answers first"?