# Why was a 1 reputation user able to post an answer on Meta?

Tags: support, reputation, meta, new-users

A user posted an answer to [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/372329/7795130) about 20 minutes ago. The user joined Stack Overflow today (Got the informed badge an hour ago so probably created the account then) and has no questions or answers.

I know that 1-rep users [can post a question regarding a question they have asked](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366603/7795130), however, I was under the impression that all other meta participation requires [5 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta).

I don't think that the user managed to have an upvoted post that got them over 5 rep before posting because at 4 minutes when I first saw the answer, I checked the account since the low reputation got my attention. It didn't have any posts on Stack Overflow main at that moment, although I guess there is the possibility that the user posted something, upvoted it from a sock puppet to get 5 rep, then deleted it immediately in order to post the meta answer from a throwaway account. However, that seems like a lot of work if they have an account capable of upvoting another already.

Is there some other rule that allows 1-rep users to post answers on Meta Stack Overflow under some condition?

Comment: A. Perhaps they had earn that rep from a now deleted post? B. Users who are active on teams can post on MSO, but since they joined today, this is kinda hard.